# How the function createUserWithEmailAndPassword() is protected from being invoked by some other website

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The initialisation code for firebase realtime database and the code to call the function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` reside in javascript file. Therefore it can be seen and copied by some other website.

How the function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` is actually protected from being invoked by some other website?

If the client side firebase object uses the **Referer** header to identify the allowed domain, can't that be intercepted and modified by the hacker? Or is it that client side firebase object communicates with the server securely (https)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not even just what you see in the JavaScript source.  There is actually nothing stopping anyone from accessing the backend APIs that implement those functions.

For example, someone could simply use the [Realtime Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database) to directly access the database from any origin, by passing your web site and JavaScript code entirely.

Also, someone could programmatically create new user accounts using the [Firebase Authentication REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth).

If you are concerned about the security of your app, the first thing you should do is learn about [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to limit the reads and writes of your database.  Firebase Authentication has its own [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits) that prevent massive abuse.

If you suspect there is abuse against your project, [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for assistance.

Comment: Thanks, Doug! I have applied the security rules using the Firebase Authentication. It is like "auth != null". Does the abuse problem still persist?

Comment: Does the rule meet the security rules meet the security needs of your app?  I can't tell you what your requirements are.

Comment: Since I am not an expert in Firebase, I think the answer is yes (it does meet the needs). Instead of using that function, now I am planning to use the Firebase pre-build UI. Thanks, Doug!